# What PCB thickness is this USB connector targeted for?

Tags: pcb, usb, connector, usb-c

The following USB Type C connector has lead lengths of 1.6 mm:
https://adam-tech.com/downloader.php?p=USB-C31-S-RA-CS1A-BK-SS-TR.pdf

What's a good PCB thickness for this connector? Also, why are there so few USB Type C connectors made for 1.6 mm thick PCBs?

Comment: Please link a website without certificate error.

Comment: Because smartphones

Comment: @Jeroen3 It's the manufacturers official website, I don't really know what to do about that.

Comment: If I had to wager a guess because through-hole is going the way of the dodo.

Comment: Most connectors for USB Type C I've seen are SMT for signals but through hole for the shield, likely because of mechanical reliability. So that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It must be obvious that PCB should be less than 1.6mm thick, although it is possible to solder the through-hole pins on a 1.6mm PCB. Typical PCB with Type-C connectors are 1.2 - 0.8mm thick.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Yes, that 1.6mm is too thick was obvious. I might try it anyway.